# Matplotlib and Tkinter - set axes navigation mode back to None

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to build a tkinter application in python 3 that integrates matplotlib's FigureCanvasTkAgg backend. I use NavigationToolbar2TkAgg to create a navigation bar widget, which creates buttons to change the axes navigation mode to "PAN" and "ZOOM". However, there isn't a button created by default that changes the navigation mode back to the default (None). I tried creating a custom function and binding it to a button: `self.select_button = tk.Button(self,command = lambda:self.ax.set_navigate_mode(None)).pack(side=tk.LEFT,anchor=tk.W)` but the axis stays in pan mode when the button is clicked. Larger code snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

class Viewer(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, collection=None, with_toolbar=True):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(8, 6)) 
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self)
        self.navbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvas, self)
        self.select_button = tk.Button(self,command = 
            lambda:self.ax.set_navigate_mode(None))
            .pack(side=tk.LEFT,anchor=tk.W)
```

Here's the documentation I was trying to use: https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NavigationToolbar2TkAgg` class comes with methods `pan` and `zoom` to toggle pan and zoom mode, respectively. Rather than calling `set_navigate_mode` directly, check for the current navigation mode using `get_navigate_mode` then call the appropriate toggle method.

```
self.navbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvas, self)
...
if self.ax.get_navigate_mode == 'PAN':
    self.navbar.pan()
elif self.ax.get_navigate_mode == 'ZOOM':
    self.navbar.zoom()
```